How to set the background color for a text box in MS Access?
Just looking at:

You In Layout view, set the background color of the CompanyName text
box to Blue, Accent 1, Lighter 80%, and set the font size to 14. Save
the form as Edit Suppliers. Close the form. Copilot Certainly! Let’s
make those adjustments to the Edit Suppliers form in Microsoft Access:
Open the form in Layout view. Locate the CompanyName text box control.
Set the background color to Blue, Accent 1, Lighter 80%. Adjust the
font size to 14. Save the form as Edit Suppliers. Close the form.
Remember to save your changes, and the Edit Suppliers form will now
have the specified background color and font size! 

I took these directions to mean the "shape fill" option under "Control Formatting" in "Format" on the ribbon.  Would there be a specific "background color" setting for a text box, or would that be the "shape fill" as above?
shape fill
